# CakePHP: Save data to 3 different models

Tags: php, database, cakephp

I'm currently trying to save data to 3 different models using a single form. They're associated like this:

Model 1 BelongsTo Model 2 
Model 2 BelongsTo Model 3

The add function is defined in the Model 1 Controller. I tried using the notation for the names of the inputs that I previously use to save multiple models and did work in that case (Model 1 hasMany Model 2, Model 3, Model 4, ... sort of dependent relationships) but this time  (which is kind of a cascade relationship) I've used saveAll, saveAssociated, but nothing works.

It always returns a database error "Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails".

It's like it tries to save the data from Model 2 without Model 1 existing yet, same with Model 3 and Model 2.

I calculate the next id for a primary key of a model and send it to the view so it can be assigned to the foreign key field of related model before it saves the data, but still, I'm not sure how I can save data to a model first then to the other, using a single form view.

I hope I explained myself properly.

Thanks.

Edit: Controller Add Function ( Model 1 = Empleado, Model 2 = Candidato , Model 3 = Cv )

```
public function agregar() {

    $this->set('proyectos', $this->Proyecto->find('list'));
    $this->set('departamentos', $this->Departamento->find('list'));

    $lastCv = $this->Cv->query("SELECT cvs.id FROM cvs ORDER BY cvs.id DESC LIMIT 1;");
    $this->set('cv_id',$lastCv[0]['cvs']['id'] + 1);

    $lastCandidato = $this->Candidato->query("SELECT candidatos.id FROM candidatos ORDER BY candidatos.id DESC LIMIT 1;");  
    $this->set('candidato_id',$lastCandidato[0]['candidatos']['id'] + 1);

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Empleado->create();
        if ($this->Empleado->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('El empleado ha sido registrado con éxito','bien');
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('No se pudo registrar el cargo'));
    }
}

//data array looks like this

$this->request->data = array(,
'Cv' => array(
    'id' => '36',
            //Rest of the Data
),
'Candidato' => array(
            'id' => '1'
    'cv_id' => '36',
     //Rest of the Data
),
'Empleado' => array(
    'candidato_id' => '1',
    //Rest of the Data
)
```

)

Comment: Your question is kind of confusing without code to look at. Update your question with the controller function you use for saving, and the view :)

Comment: The form in the view is extremely long T.T ... I'll add the controller code

Comment: Then can you put an example of what you get on post in `$this->request->data`? If it's too much, delete the field info and just keep the structure and id references. (Btw, you should not use `query()` for such simple queries you could do with find)

Comment: Ehm... I don't want you to take this in a wrong way, and I don't even know if I can do this through here, but I'm currently working on a project and I'm fairly new with cakePHP. Is there any chance that you could help me out, you know, in a more direct communication channel? (I've done some things so I'm not that lost) :|

Comment: I'm almost off working hours now, and you don't have enough rep to talk in chat yet. But like you said, you don't seem to be that lost :) Post the result of `var_dump($this->request->data)` and I'm sure someone will help.

Comment: I understand, thanks anyways, you are really kind.

Answer (score 0):

when write print_r($this->request->data) that time your data should look like below:

```
[FirstModel] => Array
    (
        [data1] => test
        [data2] => india
        [data3] => maharashtra

    )
[SecondModel] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [data1] => dfds
                [data2] => 1
                [data3] => sdf
            )

    )
```

and when you save data that time add below line
$this->FirstModel->saveAll($this->request->data['FirstModel']);
$this->SecondModel->saveAll($this->request->data['SecondModel']);